# parallel loop by foreach in R - object not fount

Tags: r, foreach, gam

I am trying to do a parallel loop in R using foreach fucntion. This loop is nested within a "for loop" and it consists in running "n" times a zigam models (package zigam) resampling the dataset at each time.
When I try to do it, I have the following error: Error in { : task 1 failed - "object "name object" does not found".
If I run the same code but using another type of model (e.g. gam function from mgcv package) the loop does work well. The following code is a quickly repeatable example:

```
  l<-c("x","o")
for (u in l) {
  px<-NULL
px<-foreach(1:2,.combine = cbind) %dopar% {
  library(dplyr)
  library(mgcv)
  library(zigam)
xyz<-data.frame(x=rpois(100,2),y=runif(100),z=rnorm(100,3),h=rnorm(100,5),o=rpois(100,1))
newx<-data.frame(y=runif(20),z=rnorm(20,3),h=rnorm(20,5))
xyz_boot<-sample_n(xyz,100,replace=T)
pro<-zipgam(xyz_boot[,u]~s(y),~s(z)+s(h),
         data=xyz_boot)
predict(pro,newx,type="response")
}
assign(paste0("p",u),px)
print(u)
}
```

The error is Error in { : task 1 failed - "object "xyz_boot" does not found". But the creation of xyz_boot is within the loop.

If I run the same code using gam and not zipgam the code works. Additionally, if I only do the foreach loop, using the name of variable "x" instead of the index xyz_boot[,u], the code works.

```
px<-NULL
px<-foreach(1:2,.combine = cbind) %dopar% {
  library(dplyr)
  library(mgcv)
  library(zigam)
xyz<-data.frame(x=rpois(100,2),y=runif(100),z=rnorm(100,3),h=rnorm(100,5),o=rpois(100,1))
newx<-data.frame(y=runif(20),z=rnorm(20,3),h=rnorm(20,5))
xyz_boot<-sample_n(xyz,100,replace=T)
pro<-zipgam(x~s(y),~s(z)+s(h),
         data=xyz_boot)
predict(pro,newx,type="response")
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try creating a formula separately: `form <- formula(paste(u,"~s(y),~s(z)+s(h)")); pro<-zipgam(form, data=xyz_boot)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the code does not work because of the following error: Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:8: unexpected ','
1: x ~s(y),^